# Show again an UImage - swipe to delete Ios -

Tags: ios, swipe

I'm using swipe to delete function's

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //add code here for when you hit delete
    NSLog(@"UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete");
    [liste removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self refreshTableView];
}
}
```

and I need to hide an UImage on the selected Cell, so I'm using this code

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{   
cellTodelete = (ListeRestoCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cellTodelete.eventImage.hidden==NO) {
    a = 1 ;
    cellTodelete.eventImage.hidden = YES ;
}    
return;
}
```

This work great, the only problem is that my Uimage is hidden even if the button Delete was not clicked, so I need to show image again if the button delete was not clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: Check now my answer is updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,

In `.h`

```
BOOL isDeleted;
NSIndexPath *selIndexPath;
```

In `.m` `loadView`

```
 isDeleted = NO;
```

/

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{   

 selIndexPath = indexPath;
cellTodelete = (ListeRestoCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cellTodelete.eventImage.hidden==NO) {
    a = 1 ;
    cellTodelete.eventImage.hidden = YES ;
}    
return;
}
```

/

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {   

    isDeleted = YES;
    //add code here for when you hit delete
    NSLog(@"UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete");
    [liste removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self refreshTableView];
}
}
```

/

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


      if(!isDeleted && selIndexPath!=nil) {

           cellTodelete = (ListeRestoCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selIndexPath];
           cellTodelete.eventImage.hidden = NO ;
      }

}
```

Comment: I try this but the methode didSelectRowAtIndexPath is never invoked whene we swipe to delete. it's only invoked whene we clic on the cell. so the hidden image is not shown again

Comment: it will call if u cancel the editing option by clicking on the tableview

Comment: no it's not called whene we cancel the editing option by clicking on the cell of tableView. it's called if we clik on the cell and the editig option is already off

Comment: Problem solved.. in case of usign the function didSelectRowAtIndexPath we must use didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath